# Progressbar not filled on API 19

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I'm building a ProgressBar dynamically at Runtime, and the Progressar is not filled on API 19 only, it works on higher APIs, the green bar that represent the percentage does not appear.

Why it doesn't work on API 19 ?

```
    private ProgressBar drawProgressBar(MatiereProgression mat) {
        ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(mContext, null, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_ProgressBar_Horizontal);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams progressLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, dpToPx(4));
        progressLayout.weight = 11;
        progressLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

        progress.setLayoutParams(progressLayout);
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setMax(100);
        progress.setMinimumHeight(0);
        progress.setMinimumWidth(150);
        progress.setProgress(mat.mProgress);
        progress.setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.progressbar));

        return progress;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug, it was the last lines, on API 19 you need to care about the line order between "setProgressDrawable" and "setProgress", it worked for me.

```
progress.setLayoutParams(progressLayout);
progress.setIndeterminate(false);
progress.setMax(100);
progress.setProgressDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.progressbar));
progress.setMinimumHeight(0);
progress.setMinimumWidth(150);
progress.setProgress(mat.mProgress);
```